# Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last)
> Validation character error rate of saved model: 8.654728% Python: 3.6.8

I am referring [this code](https://github.com/sushant097/Handwritten-Line-Text-Recognition-using-Deep-Learning-with-Tensorflow) for Handwritten line text recognition using deep learning.

Basically it is to recognize the Handwritten line text image without pre segmentation into words or characters

This is the Python App GUI Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from main import infer_by_app


class Root(Tk):

    def _init_(self):
        super(Root, self)._init_()
        self.title("Hand Written Character Recognition")
        self.minsize(1000, 400)

        self.labelFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text="Choose an Image for Text Prediction:")
        self.labelFrame.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.labelFrame2 = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text="Predicted Text:")
        self.labelFrame2.grid(column=0, row=7)
        self.label4 = ttk.Label(self.labelFrame2, text="Prediction Without AutoCorrect : ")
        self.label4.grid(column=0, row=8)
        self.label5 = ttk.Label(self.labelFrame2, text="Prediction With AutoCorrect :")
        self.label5.grid(column=0, row=9)
        self.button()

    def button(self):
        self.button_browse = ttk.Button(self.labelFrame, text="Browse", command=self.fileDialog)
        self.button_browse.grid(column=1, row=1)
        self.button_pred = ttk.Button(self.labelFrame2, text="Predict", command=self.upload)
        self.button_pred.grid(column=0, row=5)

    def fileDialog(self):

        self.filename = None
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="D:\MSc-IT\MScFinalProject\Handwritten-Line-Text-Recognition-using-Deep-Learning-with-Tensorflow-master\data", title="Select A File", filetype=
        (("PNG file", ".png"), ("all files", ".*")))

        self.label = ttk.Label(self.labelFrame, text="Image location:")
        self.label.grid(column=1, row=2)

        self.label1 = ttk.Label(self.labelFrame, text = "")
        self.label1.grid(column = 2, row = 2)
        self.label1.configure(text = self.filename)

        img = Image.open(self.filename)
        img = img.resize((800, 40))
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

        self.label2 = Label(image=photo)
        self.label2.image = photo
        self.label2.grid(column=0, row=4)

    def upload(self):
        self.option = "bestPath"
        self.destination = self.filename
        self.result = self.predText(self.destination, self.option)
        self.withoutCorrection, self.withCorrection = self.result
        #print("Prediction: ", self.withCorrection)
        self.label4.configure(text="Prediction Without AutoCorrect : " + "'" + str(self.withoutCorrection) + "'")
        self.label5.configure(text="Prediction With AutoCorrect : " + "'" + str(self.withCorrection) + "'")

    def predText(self,path,option):
        return infer_by_app(path, option)



root=Root()
root.mainloop()
```

This is the first output

[image: This is the first output]

I am getting error in second output

[image: Getting the error at second output]

> "Project/Handwritten-Line-Text-Recognition-using-Deep-Learning-with-Tensorflow-master/src/App GUI.py", line 56, in upload
> self.result = self.predText(self.destination, self.option)

Comment: `super(Root, self)._init_()` should be `super().__init__()`

Comment: I think something is wrong with your `infer_by_app` function.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of errors. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format the stacktrace directly in the question.

Comment: Hmm..
It is `def __init__(self):` not `def _init_(self):` I am not entirely sure how that works to begin with.

Comment: Also the `_init_` should be `__init__()`.